# Weird 'undefined behaviour' on recurrence formula

Tags: probability

**The problem**: You play a game, where you start with two coins. Every round, you bet a coin. You have a 1/4 chance of losing your coin and a 3/4 chance of winning a new coin. So, if you have 3 coins, you can end the round with 2 or 4 coins. You play the game, either forever or until you go bankrupt. What is the probability you go bankrupt?

**The idea**: define $f(i)$ the probability you go bankrupt, given that you have i coins. Obviously,

```
f(0)=1.
```

Also,

```
f(i) = 1/4*f(i-1) + 3/4*f(i+1)
```

(This second equation means that playing with $i$ coins, you have 1/4 chance of "reducing" your game to the $i-1$ case and 3/4 of "reducing" your game to the $i+1$ case)

**The weirdness**: These two equations seem to capture all of the problem. However, they have an infinite number of solutions. To see that, notice that the second equation just means $f(i)-f(i-1) = 3(f(i+1) - f(i))$. We can, therefore, choose $f(1)$ freely (as long as it is smaller or equal 1, and sufficiently large that it does not "force" any subsequent $f(i)$ term to be smaller than 0).

**The question**: What is going on??

Comment: What is a losing coin ?  Is it one where you lose a specified bet, or is it a coin that means you go bankrupt ?  In either event I don't think your second equation makes sense.

Comment: In how many of these solutions is it the case that the limiting value of $f(i)$ as $i\to\infty$ is *zero*?

Comment: @whuber Only one, but I expected this fact to come from the problem formulation, not to need to be added to it

Comment: I believe that the limiting value of f(i) as i→∞ is 1 and not 0, because f(i)=1 for every i. Clearly the calculation of the limit is part of the problem formulation - it is hidden in the wording. You say "What is the probability you go bankrupt?" and this means "eventually", possibly after a very large number of games, and not any limited number. If you limit the number of games to any finite number, then you are right and there are many solutions depending on your initial budget. If you take the limit of any of your equations, you see that f(i)=1 for every i is the only solution.

Comment: @ZahavaKor can you explicit a proof of this in an answer? I find it intuitive, but can't seem to make a formal proof.

Comment: @Zahava That's incorrect: the chance of eventually going bankrupt is not $1$.

Answer (score 1):

**The key is to consider a finite version of this question, the *Classical Ruin Problem*.**

> Consider the familiar gambler who wins or loses a dollar with probabilities $p$ $[=3/4]$ and $q$ $[=1/4]$, respectively.  Let his initial capital be $z$ and let him play against an adversary with initial capital $a-z$, so that the combined capital is $a$.  The game continues until the gambler's capital either is reduced to zero or has increased to $a$.  We are interested in the probability of the gambler's ruin [that is, $z \le 0$] and the probability distribution of the duration of the game.

[Feller, XIV.2]

Feller's analysis begins with the recursion and initial conditions in the question here, understanding $z$ and $a$ to be integral.  Letting $f(n)$ be the chance the gambler ultimately is ruined when $0\le n\le a$,

$$f(n) = p f(n+1) + q f(n-1)\tag{1}$$

and

$$f(0) = 1;\ f(a)=0.$$

The second boundary condition $f(a)=0$ is new, but is obvious from the rules of this finite game.  With it we obtain a *unique* solution to this difference equation,

$$f(n) = \frac{(q/p)^n - (q/p)^a}{1 - (q/p)^a};\ n=0, 1, \ldots, a,\tag{2}$$
provided $p\ne q$.

The game against an opponent with arbitrary capital is analyzed by allowing $a$ to be an arbitrarily large whole number.  From $(2)$ it is clear that for any fixed $n \gt 0$, $f(n)$ approaches $(q/p)^n$ as $a$ grows.  Consequently, for all integral $n \ge 0$, the chance of ruin must be $$f(n)=(q/p)^n.$$ With the chances given in the question, this is $((1/4) / (3/4))^n=3^{-n}$.

#### Reference

William Feller, *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*.  Volume I.  Third Edition, John Wiley & Sons, 1968: Chapter XIV.

---

#### Addendum: The Symmetric Random Walk

When $p=q$ then both equal $1/2$: wins and losses are equally likely.  The course of the game is a *Symmetric Random Walk*.  In this case formula $(2)$ is undefined.  To obtain a solution, return to the recurrence $(1)$, which can be written

$$\Delta(f)(n-1) = f(n) - f(n-1) = f(n+1) - f(n) = \Delta(f)(n).$$

That is, the *first differences* $\Delta(f)(n)$ are constant for $0\le n \lt a$.  That easily implies $f$ is a linear function of $n$ within this domain.  The unique such function connecting the point $(0,1)$ to $(a,0)$ is

$$f(n) = \frac{a-n}{a} = 1 - \frac{n}{a}.$$

The second expression makes it clear that for any $n\ge 0$, $f(n)$ approaches $1$ as $a$ grows arbitrarily large.  *In the Symmetric Random Walk, the chance of ruin is $1$ regardless of how much capital the gambler begins with.*